# Как авторизоваться через службу "google sign in" на Хром ОС при добавлении нового пользователя?

Tags: android

Есть проблема при авторизации через google sign in сервис(https://developers.google.com/... id/sign-in) на Chromebook. Проблема возникает только когда google пользователь не известен и хочешь его добавить на девайс. Добавляешь, принимаешь все политики и получается ошибка 12501. На телефоне такого не происходит, а после добавления пользователя и принятия всех политик авторизация проходит успешно. Проблема только на хром ос. Авторизация с уже известным пользователем проходит успешно.

```
try {
    GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class); // error 12501
    Log.e("TEST", "name 2 " + account.getDisplayName());
}
catch (ApiException e) {
    Log.e("TEST", "2 signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());
}
```